# Open Url in the same Tab PowerBi Embedded report

Tags: angular, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have an web application with an ambedded PowerBI report.
The report has some buttons with an web url.
If I click on this web url, the browser opens a new tab and redirect to the url.
Is there an option, that the url will be open in the same browser tab?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the report is already embedded, why not using the API and handle the `buttonClicked` event with code? See [how to handle events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/handle-events) and [the demo in the dev sandbox](https://playground.powerbi.com/dev-sandbox?showApi=reportButtonClickEvent).

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no such feature on the Power BI. Users opened a vote to add this [feature](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=f58b2fbe-1a5d-459b-9598-42ffd4ba3ee4). Currently a default feature does not seem to come. However, some users say they overcame this problem by using a drillthrough. For more [details](https://powerbi.tips/2018/09/drillthrough/)

https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-cross-report-drill-through

Comment: I didn't know how this solution can work for this problem mostly I have a button not a graph. So the only solution is to create the page in Angular and integrate the link in each button. Thanks for help